# 8mb site takes 8s to download on 10mbps broadband, why dosn't it take 0.8s?

Tags: broadband, internet-speed

Ive got a dev website home page that is 8mb (mostly due to large uncompress images, this is a dev website so this will all be sorted out and be <1mb for production).

When ive FTP'ed the site to a test server and noticed when i download view the site it takes about 8 seconds to download all of the site and assets (this is viewed from the network tab in chrome).

My internet connection is give or take 10mbps download as stated by the provided (British Telecom) and checked via speedtest.net

What im wandering is if the site is 8mb and the broadband is 10mbps why does it take c. 8 second to download the uncached site, shouldn't it be taking 0.8s ?

Comment: 10mbps is the maxim speed.  If it were to only take 0.8s you would have to have exactly 10mbps 100% of the time and that is unrealistic.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing MB and mb?

Comment: @Santeador it seems thats the issue, i wasnt aware there was a difference

Comment: @Santeador: It is important to note the capitalization.  **MB** means [megabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte), **Mb** means [megabit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit), and **MiB** means [mebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: Related question: [Why is my speed only limited to 12% of my max bandwidth?](http://superuser.com/q/51737/83694)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "8mb", you're probably saying "8 mebibytes", or "8MiB".

You have a 10Mbps downstream connection, which means "10 megabits per second".

[8MiB / 10Mbps ≈ **6.711 seconds**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8MiB%20%2F%2010Mbps)

Considering that there are also DNS lookups, other elements on the page to request, actually sending the requests to the server, and latency to the server, 8 seconds is perfectly reasonable.