# Why is task manager showing as using 66mbps when in Deluge it shows as only 6mbps?

Tags: task-manager, deluge

In task manager Deluge shows as using 66mbps on the network, in the client however it only shows as 6mbps, how is this happening? Which speed is correct?
[image]

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/51737/why-is-my-speed-only-limited-to-12-of-my-max-bandwidth

Comment: Megabyte is not megabit, task shows Bits and your program Bytes